# How do you create a function like "Data.Vector.modify", that receives a list?

Tags: haskell

Data.Vector has the following function:

```
modify :: (forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ()) -> Vector a -> Vector a
```

Is it possible to create a function such as:

```
modify :: [(forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ())] -> Vector a -> Vector a
```

I've tried

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive

unsafeModify :: [(forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())] -> V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int
unsafeModify mods vec = runST $ do
    mvec <- V.unsafeThaw vec
    sequence_ (map ($ mvec) mods)
    V.unsafeFreeze mvec
```

But I get the error

```
Muts.hs:11:28:
    Couldn't match type ‘forall s1. V.MVector s1 Int -> ST s1 ()’
                  with ‘V.MVector s Int -> ST s a0’
    Expected type: [V.MVector s Int -> ST s a0]
      Actual type: [forall s. V.MVector s Int -> ST s ()]
    Relevant bindings include
      mvec :: V.MVector s Int (bound at Muts.hs:10:5)
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘mods’
    In the first argument of ‘sequence’, namely ‘(map ($ mvec) mods)’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of `unsafeModify`. In particular, float the `forall s.` outside of the list. You want all your functions to share the same state token (which is determined by `runST`), therefore you don't need to have every function potentially using *another* `s`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Control.Monad (mapM_)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Primitive

unsafeModify :: (forall s . [MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ()]) -> V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int
unsafeModify mods vec = runST $ do
    mvec <- V.unsafeThaw vec
    mapM_ ($ mvec) mods
    V.unsafeFreeze mvec
```

Comment: This idea was on the tip of my brain, but then I got confused. Excellent.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work too, http://lpaste.net/140402 ... edit: works with additional annotation on `fns`

Answer (score 3):

The usual trick is to box up your functions, thus:

```
data Box a = Box { unBox :: forall s. MVector s a -> ST s () }
modifyAll :: [Box a] -> Vector a -> Vector a
modifyAll fs = modify (\mvector -> mapM_ (\b -> unBox b mvector) fs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ImpredicativeTypes #-}

import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import Control.Monad.ST

vmods :: [ forall s. ( V.MVector s a -> ST s () ) ] -> V.Vector a  -> V.Vector a
vmods [] v = v
vmods (m:ms) v = vmods ms $ V.modify m v

m1 v = MV.write v 0 'x'
m2 v = MV.write v 1 'y'
m3 v = MV.write v 2 'z'

test = vmods [m1,m2,m3] $ V.replicate 3 'a'
```

Comment: I was able to compile this one but not @AndrásKovács, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I was able to the other answer to _compile_ - haven't tried running it: http://lpaste.net/140367

Answer (score 1):

When type checking, GHC only ever instantiates type variables with monomorphic types. Since `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, this already rules out your intended usage, since `a` would have to be instantiated to `forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ()`, and that can't happen. This is one reason why `ImpredicativeTypes` is barely usable with GHC.

Since we'cant use the usual higher-order flow control functions, we have to write out an explicit recursive function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

unsafeModify :: [(forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())] -> V.Vector Int -> V.Vector Int
unsafeModify mods vec = runST $ do
  (mvec :: MV.MVector s Int) <- V.unsafeThaw vec

  let go :: [(forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())] -> ST s (V.Vector Int)
      go [] = V.unsafeFreeze mvec
      go (mod:mods) = do
        mod mvec
        go mods

  go mods
```

`ScopedTypeVariables` is also necessary, because we want the `s` in the return type of `go` to be the same `s` with which we bind `mvec`.

Comment: Is it actually possible to *call* that function? I would think the best approach would be the usual `newtype` trick, using a list of `newtype Modifier = Modifier (forall s . MV.MVector s Int -> ST s ())`.

Comment: Not being able to call map sounds really bad.

Comment: I wasn't able to compile a test for @AndrásKovács example, but the Modifier trick works.